# Github self-hosted runner fails to run as a service on RH Linux

Tags: github-actions-self-hosted-runners

I installed a GitHub self-hosted runner on a RH Linux EC2 instance. It runs fine in interactive mode:   ./run.sh

But when trying to run it as a service.  (sudo ./svc.sh start), it fails to start.

Active: failed
runsvc.sh  (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

Any ideas on how to get around this?

Answer (score 11):

I am running an Oracle Linux 8 instance on the Oracle Cloud and had the same issue, exactly the same error output. Very likely you have SELinux running. This is blocking your service to start. This command helped me to solve the issue:

```
chcon system_u:object_r:usr_t:s0 runsvc.sh
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Do you mean by after running above, then we can restart the systemctl service to resume it?

Comment: I'm on rocky Linux 9 and ran in a circle for longer than I will admit. Running this fixed my issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After running the `chcon` command, I could run the start but it crashed instantly with a status=1/failure.
So i ran the `chcon` command on the `run.sh` command and in the service file found in systemd I put `run.sh` instead of `svc.sh start`.

Now it starts without problems and i can get the status of the service.

```
Active: active (running) since Fri 2023-02-10 11:59:14 CET; 6s ago
Main PID: 2065992 (run.sh)
```