# Not able to start the GitHub runner as a serivce

Tags: github, github-actions, github-actions-self-hosted-runners

I am trying to install and start the GitHub runner as a service. However I am getting below error

```
[myuser@githubrunner actions-runner]$ sudo ./svc.sh install
Creating launch runner in /etc/systemd/system/actions.runner.my-org.githubrunner.service
Run as user: myuser
Run as uid: 1000
gid: 1000
Relabeled /etc/systemd/system/actions.runner.my-org.githubrunner.service from unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0 to unconfined_u:object_r:systemd_unit_file_t:s0
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/actions.runner.my-org.githubrunner.service → /etc/systemd/system/actions.runner.my-org.githubrunner.service.
[myuser@githubrunner actions-runner]$ sudo ./svc.sh start

/etc/systemd/system/actions.runner.my-org.githubrunner.service
● actions.runner.my-org.githubrunner.service - GitHub Actions Runner (my-org.githubrunner)
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/actions.runner.my-org.githubrunner.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2024-01-23 10:03:13 UTC; 10ms ago
  Process: 8114 ExecStart=/home/myuser/actions-runner/runsvc.sh (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
 Main PID: 8114 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

Jan 23 10:03:13 githubrunner systemd[1]: Started GitHub Actions Runner (my-org.githubrunner).
Jan 23 10:03:13 githubrunner systemd[1]: actions.runner.my-org.githubrunner.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Jan 23 10:03:13 githubrunner systemd[1]: actions.runner.my-org.githubrunner.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

I am expecting to start the service and expected to accept the github workflow jobs

Comment: Some of those questions help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73216851/github-action-self-host-runner-as-service-fails or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71818706/github-self-hosted-runner-fails-to-run-as-a-service-on-rh-linux/71886213#71886213